# Questions about knockout

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json, knockout.js

**1.i have 2 question about knockout on asp.net.**
server side method:

```
<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function foo() As List(Of person)
    Return New List(Of person)() From {New person With {.id = 1, .fname = "meysam"},
                                         New person With {.id = 2, .fname = "yasaman"}}.ToList
End Function
```

json and binding to knockout:

```
var VM = {};
$.getJSON("default.aspx/foo", function (data) {
    var tmp = JSON.stringify(data.d);
    VM.model =  
    ko.applyBindings(VM);
});
```

html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: model">
<h3 data-bind="text: id">
</h3>
<p>
    Name: <span data-bind="text: fname"></span>
</p>
```

but when i run in browser.No nothing will happen.`fname,id` Will be displayed.

**2.what The difference between** `$.getJSON`**and** `dataType:json`**?**

```
 $.getJSON("default.aspx/foo", function (data) {
    var tmp = JSON.stringify(data.d);
});
```

and

```
$.ajax({
type:"post",
url:"default.aspx/foo",
contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
dataType:"json",
success:function(data){}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your knockout question:

Here's code to solve your issue:

#### Output

[image]

#### ASPX code behind

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static IEnumerable<KnoPerson> GetPeople()
    {
        return Builder<KnoPerson>.CreateListOfSize(10).Build();
    }

public class KnoPerson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

#### ASPX

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var model = {};
        $.ajax({
            url: "KnockoutBindingFromPageMethod.aspx/GetPeople",
            data: null,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (myData) {
                model.people = ko.mapping.fromJS(myData.d);
                model.yo = ko.observable("plop");
                ko.applyBindings(model);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

    <div data-bind="text: yo"></div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: people">
        <h3 data-bind="text: ID"></h3>
        <p>
            Name: <span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

---

> 2.what The difference between $.getJSONand dataType:json?

`.getJSON` is a shortcut, and it internally uses `.ajax`

The `.getJSON` function sets the following properties:

- `dataType: “json”`
- `type: "GET"`

Answer (score 1):

So, this really should be two *actual* questions, but anywho (in reverse order!):

2: From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/): `$.getJSON` is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

So they are the same.

1: Your attempt to call `JSON.stringify()` on the result of a `getJSON` call is redundant. `getJSON` already does that. The problem is two-fold: neither of those parsers can parse .net lists (I might be wrong about this, but I am 60% sure). In either case, the better solution would be to serialize the list into JSON in the web method, and return already parsed JSON. .NET has [this ability built-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx).

Two, your list doesn't have a `d` property. So even when you sort that part out, you are going to get an undefined error.